Evolutionarily, why do some animals perceive eye contact as a sign of aggression?
It's said that species like dogs and bears perceive eye contact as a sign of aggression. Primates -- including us humans, in many of the world's cultures -- use eye contact in this way as well, to the point where zoo visitors are advised to avoid their gaze when possible.
Nothing seems intuitively "aggressive" about looking at someone looking at you. So then, why is eye contact commonly perceived as a form of aggression, even across species? Is there an advantage to perceiving eye contact as aggressive?

I am of the belief that this question is better asked with the "Evolutionary" part left off. It is best not to specify how you want someone to answer. This question is better answered with animal neuroscience than with some far-fetched answer about how evolution and eye contact are related.

Perhaps that would be an alternative approach, but I believe that the evolutionary approach offers a relevant and valid approach when considered in conjunction with the neuroscience - we don't want to exclude things from our toolkit do we? @Arrow Edited to add: Also worth taking into account; the condition the animals are kept in, their health, their conditioning and developmental stage. Oh, and their gender and if they've young....

Eye contact being perceived as aggressive across species, including in humans, stems from evolutionary and behavioural factors. In primates and humans, direct eye contact can signal dominance, threat, or territoriality. This is rooted in survival instincts where maintaining a safe distance and avoiding confrontation are advantageous. In social species, interpreting eye contact as aggressive helps in navigating hierarchical structures and minimising conflict. This perception likely evolved as a way to establish boundaries and maintain order within groups. So, even though eye contact itself isn't inherently aggressive, seeing it that way helps animals and us humans promote social cohesion and keep things in line.
For a popular science publication discussion see here.
Also, keep in mind that the "aggressive" interpretation is not solely due to a gaze/stare. There are still tiny facial expressions and changes in facial muscles that provide cues.

different but related: Term for a prey animal's recognition that something potentially threatening is looking at it?

Savalli et al 2016 argues this isn't applicable to dogs: when dogs go into threat displays there's eye contact, but its the other gestures that are conveying the threat. Specifically, Eye Contact Is Crucial for Referential Communication in Pet Dogs by Carine Savalli et al in PLoS One 2016 argues dogs extensively use eye contact to communicate to their owners (but they are not threatening their owners), whilst primates use vocalisation for communication for equivalent communication of needs or requests. Thus, when primates use threat displays eye contact is key because its not used in request behaviour, whilst Savalli et al 2016 is arguing in dogs eye contact ain't for threats, but critical non-verbal communication to convey their needs to owners. In summary, you don't bite the hand that feeds you, you don't use threat displays for requests.  The dogs system of non-verbal communication isn't trivial, but intricate involving obtaining eye-contact as the initiation of communication (see the diagram below). The study sample size was not huge "Twelve male and ten female" but it is a convincing behavioural study.

My personal view is that it is very clear from Russian breeding program for fox domestication - and their owners reports - that dogs have been through extensive layers of evolutionary selection far beyond simply "tolerating humans", which is what domesticated foxes display after considerable directed selection.
